# Java Scanner and loop

Tags: java, loops, input

I dont know whats wrong with me right now. I dont know if im tired or something but what's wrong with this code

```
        message = scanner.nextLine();

    while ((!message.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) || (!message.equalsIgnoreCase("read")))
    {
        System.out.println("WTF");
        Encrypt(message, salt);
        message = scanner.nextLine();
    }
```

for some reason, even though i for message i write read or exit the program still goes through the loop once ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably meant to use `&&`:

```
while ((!message.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) && (!message.equalsIgnoreCase("read")))
```

As it is right now, of course the message will not equal one of them. So it loops forever.